# How to append in python for telegram bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, append, telegram, telepot

I am doing a telegram bot with something like a calculator, I'm trying to append all the inputted values so that i can save the value in a variable.

```
        numpad = InlineKeyboardMarkup(inline_keyboard=[
            [InlineKeyboardButton(text='1', callback_data= '1'),
            InlineKeyboardButton(text='2', callback_data= '2'),
            InlineKeyboardButton(text='3', callback_data= '3')],
            [InlineKeyboardButton(text='4', callback_data= '4'),
            InlineKeyboardButton(text='5', callback_data= '5'),
            InlineKeyboardButton(text='6', callback_data= '6')],
            [InlineKeyboardButton(text='7', callback_data= '7'),
            InlineKeyboardButton(text='8', callback_data= '8'),
            InlineKeyboardButton(text='9', callback_data='9')],
            [InlineKeyboardButton(text='0', callback_data='0'),
             InlineKeyboardButton(text='.', callback_data='.')],
            [InlineKeyboardButton(text='ENTER', callback_data='done')],
                               ])

        bot.sendMessage(from_id, 'How much u wanna change bro', reply_markup=numpad)

    if query_data in ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0']:
        print('hi')
        amt= []
        for query_data in amt:
            amt.append(query_data)
            z = list[amt]
    if query_data == 'done':
        bot.sendMessage(from_id, "is this the amount you want to change{}?".format(z))
        print (z)
```

Comment: How are you receiving the user's response? Where is the code for that?

Comment: user input is from the numpad in telegram bot. My shell is printing out the input but just not appending into the list "amt"

Answer (score 0):

here:

```
for query_data in amt:
    amt.append(query_data)
    z = list[amt]
```

in line 1, Do your mean of "amt", Is "numpad"? because "mean" is a Empty list and you want fill it after "for". So maybe the correct code is :

```
for query_data in numpad:
    amt.append(query_data)
    z = list[amt]
```

Comment: isn't numpad just a keyboard variable?

Comment: oh sorry. i didn't work with telegram bot python library. but just i think only this Has a value so this can insert into "for". Generally You should look for a variable that has the amount of incoming and paste it. instead of "amt" insert The variable contains user inputs and instead of "query_data"s insert name of "for"'s variables. Also, if you're having trouble with "for", see:  https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem lies in this part of the code:

```
    amt= []
    for query_data in amt:
        amt.append(query_data)
        z = list[amt]
```

I'm not entirely sure about the python syntax<sup>1</sup>, but this seems to create a new variable `query_data` for the scope of the for loop.
This means that you do your loop for every element of `amt`. But `amt` is empty, so you don't do the loop at all.
I'm not certain what your loop is intended to do, but wouldn't just using a variable that exists over the time of all the inputs (for the easiest example: a global variable) suit your needs better? If you had a global `amt`, you could replace that code block with

```
amt.append(query_data)
z = list[amt]
```

Be aware though, that a global variable will cause trouble as soon as you have more than one user simultaneously.

---

[1] Note that python just replaces your `amt` variable. Here's an example:

```
>>> alpha = []
>>> beta = [1,2,3]
>>> for alpha in beta:
...     print(1)
...
1
1
1
>>> alpha
3
```

So even though my `alpha` was a list, it became an integer of value `3`